# multiple users using mysql connection in php

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, connection

I am making a website that needs to access a data from a MySQL database, with the code written in PHP.

This is my connection call right now:

```
$connection = mysql_connect("url", "username", "password", true);
$db_select = mysql_select_db("db_name", $connection);
```

Multiple users will be using the website at once, and all of them will be accessing the database at the same time. *User1* needs to have his purchases displayed, and *user2* needs the same etc...

Right now if one user goes on the site, everything is fine. However, if two users try and access the site at the same time, the second user will get an application error (Facebook).

I am assuming the problem is that this second user tries to access the database on the same connection made by the first user which crashes. However, I set the `new_link` to `true`, so I'm not sure why this still isn't working. Is there something I am not thinking of?

Comment: what's the exact issue, "application error (facebook)" is not very descriptive.

Comment: There is not remotely enough information here to help you.  You start off talking about MySQL and PHP, but your error is actually related to Facebook?  What is the error, and where is the code causing the problem?  Multiple connections can be made to the MySQL server without problem, unless you have specifically configured it to only allow one connection.

Comment: this is an app that I am building on facebook, but it acts like a regular webpage. The problem is that the error I am getting is literally just that: application error. So I have no idea what it could be. However, since there are no other errors with the site when running a single user, I am guessing that it has to do with the mysql connection.

Comment: Application error isn't a PHP error I've seen, are you sure this isn't being thrown by something proprietary to Facebook? Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','1');` at the top of your script to see if there is any additional output. As mentioned in a previous comment, mysql is designed for concurrent connections and there should be no problem unless expressly defined in the mysql config. You could also change the connection to `$connection = mysql_connect("url", "username", "password", true) or die(mysql_error());` to quadruple check it's not mysql.

Comment: yes i see that my assumption was wrong. I guess it might be with facebook somewhere. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is wrong. Each user actually uses different connection to mysql.